# After php url slash I got a different page

Tags: php

How to resolve this issue. If I type localhost/login.php/ I should redirect localhost/login.php. If PHP_SELF is used in your page then a user can enter a slash (/) and then some Cross Site Scripting (XSS) commands to execute. How to solve this issue. Php more secure. 
[login.php/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g6gH.png)

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>/">
                        <script>
                            alert('hacked')

                        </script>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <div class="form-group form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-button">
                            <button id="submit" type="submit" class="ibtn">Login</button> <a href="recover.php">Forget password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? In PHP if there is stuff after a / then it goes to that file. Plus a hacker cannot modify $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]. That is a server only value. Adding a slash does not prevent hackers.

Comment: Then what is xxs? Cross site scripting.

Comment: The issue is that you can't cross site script by just going to a / url. Cross site scripting is when you send bad information to a url.